# The distorted and blinking textures, white rectangles - SFML C++

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, textures, sfml

I encountered a problem while I was writing a card game using C++ and an SFML library. When I execute the application, there are no card textures displayed, the only thing I see are white rectangles or the cards’ textures distorted in a strange way.
I have already searched through all the pages I possibly could and didn’t find the answer. Why do these textures sometimes appear and blink? Why are there the white rectangles another time?
What I found out is that: it’s due to the missing textures. In fact, I use textures as properties of the object. Therefore, they are in memory as long as they need to be rendered on the screen by the SFML rendering function.
So, there must be some type of flaw in my code. I have the following lines of code (To be honest, there is much more code. I extracted these lines providing what matters here):

**Card.cpp**

```
 class Card {
        public:
            static std::string textureDirectory;
            Card(unsigned int id);
            void render(sf::RenderWindow &window);
        private:
            unsigned int id;
            sf::Sprite background;
            sf::Texture texture;
            void loadTexture();
    };
    
    std::string Card::textureDirectory = "media/textures/cards/";
    
void Card::render(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    window.draw(this->background);
}

void Card::loadTexture(){
    std::string extension = ".png";
    std::string cardIdAsString = std::to_string(this->id);
    if (!this->texture.loadFromFile( Card::textureDirectory + cardIdAsString + extension ))
        std::cout << "Couldn't load the texture: " << cardIdAsString << extension;
}

Card::Card(unsigned int id){
    this->id = id;
    this->loadTexture();
}
```

**Character.cpp**

```
class Character {
private:
    std::vector <Card> deck;
public:
    Character();
    void renderCards(sf::RenderWindow& window);
private:
    void createDeck();
    void addToDeckCardWithId(unsigned int id);
};

void Character::addToDeckCardWithId(unsigned int id){
    this->deck.push_back( Card(id) );
}

void Character::createDeck(){
    this->addToDeckCardWithId(0);
    this->addToDeckCardWithId(0);
}

Character::Character(){
    this->createDeck();
}

void Character::renderCards(sf::RenderWindow& window){
    int size = this->deck.size();
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        this->deck.at(i).render(window);
}
```

All the textures are loaded properly so it's not the problem with loading them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in managing textures and the memory management. In order to solve it I had to write a TextureManagement or more broadly a AssetManagement class. I found a great source for doing so: [YouTube video on writing the SFML asset manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY2pCfMqnik)

I deem this Stackoverflow question very helpful as it contains comprehensive answer as well: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951870/sfml-texture-displaying-as-a-white-box)